# Disable submit button with jQuery Form Plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins, submit

Hi I'm trying to disable a submit button after clicking on it. I'm also using a jQuery Form plugin so my code looks like :

```
$('#passwordForm').ajaxForm({
            dataType:  'json',
            beforeSubmit:  disableButton,
            success:   processPassword
        });
```

and my disableButton function is :

```
function disableButton(formData, jqForm, options) {
    jqForm[0].children('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

But now it looks like my whole form is disabled and nothing is send to the server! Does it work that way? If I disable a submit button in beforeSubmit function ( but the form is already submitted) my whole form will be disabled? How to solve this problem?

Thanks
Dawid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you're indexing the jqForm parameter, which returns the DOM element for the form. This doesn't have a children() function.

jqForm is a jQuery object, so you can just call `jqForm.children()`. However, I'd suggest calling `jqForm.find()` instead, since children only searches the immediate children, not all children.

Disabling fields on submit is a tricky issue. Usually what I'll do is attach a do-nothing event handler instead.

Something like this:

```
$('#passwordForm').ajaxForm({
    dataType:  'json',
    beforeSubmit:  disableButton,
    success:   processPassword
});

function disableButton(data, $form, opts) {
    $form.find('input:submit').val("Please wait...").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
}
```

So the user can click on it, but nothing will happen :)

Comment: Only problem is the submit button is "disabled" like this until I refresh the page. How could I enable this button in a success function?

Comment: `$form.find('input:submit').val("Submit Form").unbind('click')`. If you need to restore previous functionality to the submit button, you'll have to break out the event handlers into their own functions, and read up on how jQuery binds and unbinds events.

Answer (score 2):

You say the form is submitted, but you disable the submit button in the `beforeSubmit`. As the name beforeSubmit suggests, this is triggered before the form is actually submitted. Without a enabled submit button, you cannot submit a form.

Read more about disabled form elements here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12 . To make a long story short: "Disabled controls cannot be successful."

Comment: How would you do this then? I've seen forms that apparently disable the submit button while processing.

Comment: @Chriszuma, he should use Google and something like this: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-disable-submit-button-after-clicked-with-jquery/

Comment: Doesn't that have the same problem though? It looks like they're doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are your form elements enabled? To ensure it, try this:

```
function disableButton(formData, jqForm, options) {
    jqForm[0].find(':input').attr('disabled', false);
    jqForm[0].find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
function disableButton(formData, jqForm, options) {
    jqForm[0].children('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: This should not make any difference.

Comment: If the selector is wrong ".children" will give all the child elements within the form and it will apply disabled attribute to all those elements.

Comment: `input[type=submit]` and `input[type="submit"]` are equivalent. This is not the issue.